# ¿Porque mi procedimiento almacenado no guarda correctamente los valores que ingreso? SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

estoy trabajando con reporting service y quiero almacenar la lista de valores que el usuario ingresa a mi tabla por lo que realice un procedimiento que lo hiciera y todo estaba perfecto ya que hacia pruebas con datos de 0-1000 como mucho, pero a la hora de agregar más de 3000 siempre me quita 15 registros lo cual no hacia si eran menos de 3000, que es lo que puede estar pasando aqui?

Les muestro mi SP el cual me ayuda a guardar mis valores:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC spu_SetUserSetting
      (
         @UserID varchar(100),
         @Report varchar(100),
         @Setting varchar(100),
         @Value varchar(max)
      )
   AS
   BEGIN
    
    IF EXISTS (select UserID from tblUserSetting where UserID=@UserID and Report=@Report)
        BEGIN
            IF @Value = ''
                PRINT 'NO SE INGRESO NADA'
            ELSE
                UPDATE tblUserSetting
                 SET Val=@Value
                 WHERE UserID=@UserID
                 AND Report=@Report
                 AND Setting=@Setting
            
                --Return the new setting
                SELECT @Value AS Val
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN 
         --Now add the new setting
          INSERT INTO tblUserSetting
             (UserID, Report, Setting, Val)
          VALUES
             (@UserID, @Report, @Setting, @Value)
             --Return the new setting
                SELECT @Value AS Val
        END    

     END  
GO
```

Y esta seria la estructura de mi tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE tblUserSetting(
      ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
      UserID varchar(100) NULL,
      Report varchar(100) NULL,
      Setting varchar(100) NULL,
      Val varchar(max) NULL
)
```

Por ultimo si me permiten, esta es la manera en como guarda los valores a la tabla, realmente no se si sea por esto ya que no se me ocurrio una mejor manera de almacenarlos y utilizar sus valores, si realmente es el problema les pido su ayuda para saber como hacerlo de mejor manera. Agradezco su tiempo y muchas gracias por su apoyo!

[image: Tabla]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error está en que tu sentencia `exists` omite uno de los criterios que utilizas en la sentencia `update`.

Lo que ocurre es que hay ciertas llamadas que cumplan con la sentencia exists, porque si hay un registro para ese `userId` y `Report`, que luego no actualizan ningún registro, porque el que existe es de diferente `Setting`, por tanto la sentencia update actualiza 0 registros.

Para evitar esta inconsistencia, puedes centralizar la lógica de búsqueda, inserción y actualización en una única sentencia [`merge`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql), que existe justamente para eso.

En una única sentencia, el propio motor se encarga de validar si el registro existe, si lo encuentra lo actualiza con la sentencia `when matched` y si no, lo inserta con la sentencia `when not matched by target`.

El procedimiento almacenado luciría como el siguiente:

```sql
create or alter proc spu_SetUserSetting (
    @UserID varchar(100)
  , @Report varchar(100)
  , @Setting varchar(100)
  , @Value varchar(max)
)
as
begin
  if @Value = ''
    print 'NO SE INGRESO NADA'
  else
    merge
     into tblUserSetting dst
    using (select @UserID UserID, @Report Report, @Setting Setting, @Value Val) as src
       on dst.UserID = src.UserID
      and dst.Report = src.Report
      and dst.Setting = src.Setting
     when matched then 
          update
             set Val = src.Val
     when not matched by target then
          insert (UserId, Report, Setting, Val)
          values (src.UserId, src.Report, src.Setting, src.Val);
--Return the new setting
  select @Value AS Val;
end
go
```

Comment: Y sobre la parte de almacenar mi lista de valores, ¿Crees que es una buena manera de guardarlos asi? Realmente no supe como hacer esto y aunque no se mucho sql creo que no es la mejor manera, considerarias darme tu opinion?

Comment: No podría opinar realmente sin saber qué objetivo persigues. De entrada diría que si funciona, para comenzar, está bien. Quizás pueda perfeccionarse, pero lo más importante ya lo hace.

Answer (score 1):

Dejando de lado el hecho de que el diseño de la tabla es cuestionable, creo que el problema viene porque no incluiste la comparación de la columna `Setting` en tu `IF EXISTS`.

Por otro lado, tu código es propenso a problemas de concurrencia (aunque no creo que sea el caso aquí), por lo que sugiero modificarlo un poco.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC spu_SetUserSetting
(
    @UserID varchar(100),
    @Report varchar(100),
    @Setting varchar(100),
    @Value varchar(max)
)
AS

IF @Value = ''
    PRINT 'NO SE INGRESO NADA'
ELSE
BEGIN
    UPDATE tblUserSetting
       SET Val = @Value
     WHERE UserID  = @UserID
       AND Report  = @Report
       AND Setting = @Setting;
        
    INSERT INTO tblUserSetting(
        UserID, 
        Report, 
        Setting, 
        Val
    )
    SELECT @UserID, 
            @Report, 
            @Setting, 
            @Value
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (select UserID 
                        from tblUserSetting 
                        where UserID = @UserID 
                        and Report   = @Report
                        AND Setting  = @Setting --Esta comparación no estaba
                     );
END
                              
--Return the new setting
SELECT @Value AS Val;
GO
```